# Can Google's Container OS be used with gRPC on Compute Engine?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, grpc, google-container-os

My high-level architecture is described in [Cloud Endpoints for gRPC](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/about-grpc#api_management).

The **Server** below is a Compute Engine instance with Docker installed, running two containers (the ESP, and my server):

[image]

As per [Getting started with gRPC on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-compute-engine-docker), I SSH into the VM and install Docker on the instance (see [Install Docker on the VM instance](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-compute-engine-docker#install_docker_on_the_vm_instance)). Finally I pull down the two Docker Containers (ESP and my server) and `run` them.

I've been reading around [Container-Optimized OS from Google](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/).

Rather than provisioning an instance with an OS and then installing Docker, I could just provision the OS with a [Container-Optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/), and then pull-down my containers and run them.

However the only [gRPC tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/tutorials) are for [gRPC on Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes-engine), [gRPC on Kubernetes](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-kubernetes), and [gRPC on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-compute-engine-docker). There is no mention of Container OS.

Has anyone used Container OS with gRPC, or can anyone see why this wouldn't work?

[Creating an instance for advanced scenarios](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/create-configure-instance#advanced) looks relevant because it states:

> Use this method to [...] deploy multiple containers, and to use
>   cloud-init for advanced configuration.

For context, I'm trying to move to CI/CD in Google Cloud, and removing the need to install Docker would be a step in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically follow almost the same instructions in the [*Getting started with gRPC on Compute Engine*](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-compute-engine-docker) guide to deploy your gRPC server with the ESP on Container-Optimized OS. In your case, just see Container-Optimized OS as an OS with pre-installed Docker (there are more features but, in your case, only this one is interesting).

It is possible to use `cloud-init` if you want to **automate** the startup of your Docker containers (gRPC server + ESP) when the VM instance starts. The following `cloud-init.cfg` file automates the startup of the same containers presented in the documentation examples (with [bookstore sample app](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/bookstore-grpc)). You can replace the *Creating a Compute Engine instance* part with two steps.

#### Create a `cloud-init` config file

Create `cloud-init.cfg` with the following content :

```
#cloud-config

runcmd:
- docker network create --driver bridge esp_net
- docker run 
    --detach
    --name=bookstore
    --net=esp_net
    gcr.io/endpointsv2/python-grpc-bookstore-server:1
- docker run
    --detach
    --name=esp
    --net=esp_net
    --publish=80:9000
    gcr.io/endpoints-release/endpoints-runtime:1
    --service=bookstore.endpoints.<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>.cloud.goog
    --rollout_strategy=managed
    --http2_port=9000
    --backend=grpc://bookstore:8000
```

Just after starting the instance, `cloud-init` will read this configuration and :

- create a Docker network (`esp_net`)
- run the bookstore container
- run the ESP container. In this container startup command, replace `<YOUR_PROJECT_ID>` with your project ID (or replace the whole `--service` option depending on your service name)

#### Create a Compute Engine instance with Container-Optimized OS

You can create the instance from the Console, or via the command-line :

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-1 \
    --zone=us-east1-b \
    --machine-type=n1-standard-1 \
    --tags=http-server,https-server \
    --image=cos-73-11647-267-0 \
    --image-project=cos-cloud \
    --metadata-from-file user-data=cloud-init.cfg
```

The `--metadata-from-file` will populate `user-data` metadata with the contents of `cloud-init.cfg`. This `cloud-init` config will be taken into account when the instance will start.

You can validate this works by :

- SSHing into `instance-1`, and running `docker ps` to see your running containers (gRPC server + ESP). You may experience some delay between the startup of your instance and the startup of both containers
- calling your gRPC service with a client. For example (always with the bookstore application presented in the docs) :

```
INSTANCE_IP=$(gcloud compute instances describe instance-1 --zone us-east1-b --format="value(network_interfaces[0].accessConfigs.natIP)")
python bookstore_client.py --host $INSTANCE_IP --port 80 # returns a valid response
```

Note that you can also choose to not use `cloud-init`. You can directly run the `docker run` commands (the same as in `cloud-init.cfg` file) on your VM with Container-Optimized OS, exactly like you would do on any other OS.